# Tensorflow fails with the error: InvalidArgumentError: Node 'initial_state': Unknown input node 'initial_state/input'

Tags: tensorflow

The source-code with the entire exception trace can be found [here](https://github.com/apiltamang/deep-learning/blob/master/tv-script-generation/dlnd_tv_script_generation.ipynb). This is very weird because it occurs in the tf.global_variables_initializer() method in the "Train" section of the code. Why would this method fail trying to get the "initial_state" variable? The line right above it shows that this variable is clearly present in global scope.

The code is part of a MOOC, and strangely enough nobody else in the class (>5000) seems to have experienced that problem...

Hmmm..What could I be missing..

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Node 'init_3/NoOp': Unknown input node '^is_training/Assign'
```

It turns out I had `with tf.device('/gpu:0')` when I was in fact running TensorFlow on CPU.